# outputting how many duplicates each item has in the list and vertically output it, where each duplicate is represented with a ' * '

Tags: python

The code is supposed to take a bunch of input from the user and put it into a list and than output how many duplicates each item has. E.g. lets say the user inputs a,b,a,c,c I want my output to be like this:

```
a: **   

b: *

c: **
```

each `'*'` represents a duplicate. my code gives me this: `{a: 2, b: 1, c: 2}`

```
from collections import Counter
reports = 0
graph1 = []
print("Enter in this format: # of reports, StartDate, EndDate. E.g. 5 20200401 20200403")
nor, start, end = input().split()
nor = int(nor)
print("Enter in this format: LabID, Date, # of cases. E.g. IWK 20200401 1")
while reports < nor:
   place, date, noc = input().split()
   graph1.append(int(date))
reports = reports + 1
graph1.sort()
a = dict(Counter(graph1))
print(a)
```

i tried doing this: print(* a, sep='\n') this makes the stuff in the list output vertically
but it doesn't output the counter and is there a way to change the 2, 1, 2 into '*'

Comment: You want to convert [2, 1, 2] (graph) variable into an output like: `a: ** \nb: * \nc: **` right?

Comment: `number * '*'` results in  _number_ of asterisks

Comment: keidakida - yes i want the number of duplicates in the list to be represented by a ' * ' and output it verticall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna pick it up from your result i.e. `{a: 2, b: 1, c: 2}`. You can simple iterate through your dictionary this way:

```
x = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
for k,j in x.items():
    print(k,':',j*'*', '\n')
```

The print statement prints `k` the dictionary key, a colon (`:`) and product(`*`) of `j`(the value corresponding to the key), the string `'*'` and `'\n'`(new line)

> Result

```
a : **

b : *

c : **
```